# Microsoft Access query won't order certain numbers

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-office

I'm working on modifying an access application for my work. I'm generating a report that has categories denoted by integers 1-11. Each subsection of these categories is a decimal such as 1.01,1.02,1.03, etc. When I generate the report each subsection from 1 to 9 is in ascending order, i.e., 1.01 to 1.11 are in order. When it gets to 10 and 11, the categories are not in order, i.e., 10.01, 10.04, 10.03, 10.02, etc. When I change the values of each subsection to 3 digits such as 10.1, 10.2, etc, they are sorted in correct order. It just seems to break ordering when there are 4 or more digits on any side of the decimal. I'm not overly familiar with access or sql in general so I'm not sure on how to solve this problem other then editing the values of 10 and 11 to be 3 digits. The numbers for the subsection are stored in text field type. I've changed it to numbers and currency, neither of which resulted in a change in ordering. Does anyone have an idea why this is happening? I apologize if I left out any critical information. Please let me know if there is any additional details I can provide.

Answer (score 0):

The following is trick that you can use, when you have numbers stored as character strings and want to order them:

```
order by len(category), category
```